# Padrão de Projeto para Filtros

Tags: c#, winforms, design-pattern

Primeiramente, filtro no meu atual contexto é uma lista de objetos a serem utilizados em controles do tipo ComboBox para que o usuário possa escolher dentre as opções.

Meu cenário:
Tela 1 - Possui filtros de empresas, estoques, clientes, formas de pagamento.
Tela 2 - Possui filtros de empresas e estoques.
Tela 3 - Possui filtros de clientes, cidades, estados.

Meu objetivo é implementar um padrão de projeto que utilize uma mesma estrutura, ex: FiltroTela, e vá adicionando dentro os filtros (empresas, clientes, estoques) dependendo da tela que o solicitou.

Essas telas são de um projeto windows forms, a solicitação será feita a um WCF Service, que irá fazer a consulta em uma base de dados e devolver a estrutura com todos os filtros ao client (windows forms).

Algo em torno de, WCF Service eu "Tela 1" quero os filtros empresas, estoques, clientes e formas de pagamento, ao receber a msg de volta, faria o respectivo binding para cada controle.

Alguém consegue me indicar um padrão de projeto para resolver essa questão?

Comment: Crie view, e partir dae crie os filtros

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @LuizVichiatto, mas a camada de acesso a dados já existe e inclusive já utilizo views, meu problema mesmo é encaixar um design patterns para tratar a ida e vinda da lista de objetos (filtros) ao longo do projeto.

Comment: usa como parametro no sql

Answer (score 3):

Você pode combinar a resposta do @RogerOliveira no lado do SQL com o padrão [*Builder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) e [Interfaces Fluentes](http://luizricardo.org/2013/08/construindo-objetos-de-forma-inteligente-builder-pattern-e-fluent-interfaces/) no lado do C#.

Basicamente você usaria o filtro assim:

```
new FiltroTelaBuilder().porEmpresa(empresa).build();
```

Ou assim:

```
new FiltroTelaBuilder().porCliente(cliente).build();
```

Ou assim:

```
new FiltroTelaBuilder().porEmpresa(empresa).porCliente(cliente).build();
```

Em todos os casos o método `build()` retorna uma instância imutável de `FiltroTela`.

Existem diferentes formas de implementar esse padrão. Esse é o mais comum.

Answer (score 3):

> Resposta originalmente postada no corpo da pergunta por seu próprio autor

Bom, encontrei um padrão que me ajudou e muito, o Decorator, segue um link de referência "[Decorator Design Pattern](http://www.devmedia.com.br/um-pattern-em-c-por-dia-decorator-pattern-estrutural/21747)" e abaixo um pequeno exemplo de como ficou a implementação da montagem dos filtros, que me atende por tela:

```
private Dictionary<string, object> FiltroTela1()
    {
        IFilter filtro = new Filter();
        filtro = new FilterCompany(filtro);
        filtro = new FilterCustomer(filtro);
        filtro = new FilterPaymentType(filtro);
        return filtro.Filters();
    }

private Dictionary<string, object> FiltroTela2()
    {
        IFilter filtro = new Filter();
        filtro = new FilterCustomer(filtro);
        filtro = new FilterPaymentType(filtro);
        return filtro.Filters();
    }
```

Os dois exemplos acima utiliza o Decorator para "decorar" meu objeto Filtro com os filtros necessários para cada tela, e o método "Filters" obtém de cada filtro o tipo e um objeto para ser utilizado como critério na busca do filtro.

Na outra ponta "Server", utilizo o mesmo padrão, ele analisa o dicionário recebido e vai obtendo da base de dados os filtros solicitado, monta um novo filtro, porém com a lista de cada um e devolve pra tela, que por sua vez faz a análise dos filtros recebidos e realiza o binding para o respectivo controle.

Answer (score 1):

Eu passo os filtros como parametros na Stored Procedure usando esse sql:

```
@parametro is null or campo = @parametro
```

Assim qdo vc passar null no parametro ele ira ignorar, dai simplesmente repassa sempre parametros pra SP se forem nulos tu trata antes.